# Python-Requests slow on large responses

Tags: performance, http, network-programming, python-requests

I'm using python-requests to test out the response times for api calls made to a service. The responses that comes back are around 1-1.5MB, but what I'm seeing is that most of that time is spent parsing the responses chunked at 10KB (in the request module's content method).
If I make concurrent requests using an async framework like grequests, the response times are significantly slower.

4 concurrent requests

```
Elapsed: 0.807070970535 <- response time of reading first byte
Elapsed: 0.816656827927 <- response time of reading first byte
Elapsed: 0.797511100769 <- response time of reading first byte
Elapsed: 0.871026039124 <- response time of reading first byte
method took content 5.80513095856 <- response time reading entire response
method took content 5.89753890038 <- response time reading entire response
method took content 7.95831394196 <- response time reading entire response
method took content 8.77741289139 <- response time reading entire response
```

With one request, the response time reading the entire response is just around 2 seconds. Why does consuming multiple 1.5MB responses take 5-8 seconds? Is it because the thread is context switching between reading in the 4 different responses?
Is it because of network latency (probably not the only problem since the server I'm making the requests to can take much higher traffic)? Or is it because of resource starvation with the cpu?
Are there any other alternate httplib frameworks that will dramatically improve the speed?

Thanks!